# Instafeed and DOM manipulation

Tags: jquery, dom, instagram

I'm using Instafeed.js to pull images from instagram. It's working just fine. Here's a link to the working project.

http://www.craftysnaps.com

The problem is, I can't us jQuery to make functionally changes. Here's what I am using to append the images to the div called `#content`.

```
var feed = new Instafeed({  
    target: 'content',  
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'craftysnaps',
    clientId: 'c57635b97e7440dd8bacf38304db4e07',
    resolution: 'standard_resolution',
     template: '<article><img src="{{image}}" /><div class="likes">{{likes}}</div><div class="location">{{location}}</div><div class="caption">{{caption}}</div><div class="more"><a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="images/more.png" /></div></a></article>'
    });     
feed.run();
```

In the template section I am calling the location of the instagram post. I'd like to add a `geopin` image right about the *location* in it's own `div`, but if the *location* is null I'd like to hide the image. I can do that easily by coding something like this.

```
if($(".location").html().length ==0){
   $(".hidethisimage").hide();
}
```

But since none of the DIVs in my template really exist in the DOM, I can't add functionality to them. Any ideas here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tested but I assume you may use Instafeed's `after` callback to manipulate elements after they have been (dynamically) added to the DOM, something like

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
    target: 'content',
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'craftysnaps',
    clientId: 'c57635b97e7440dd8bacf38304db4e07',
    resolution: 'standard_resolution',
    template: '<article><img src="{{image}}" /><div class="likes">{{likes}}</div><div class="location">{{location}}</div><div class="caption">{{caption}}</div><div class="more"><a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="images/more.png" /></div></a></article>',
    after: function () {
        if ($(".location").is(":empty")) {
            $(".location").parent("article").hide();
        }
    }
});
feed.run();
```